# Developer tools cause a freeze in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, freeze, crash-dumps, short

I have just installed Google Chrome and started to check my web application. Since I have a bug either in HTML or in Javascript I set a breakpoint in the function to be called ... or at least I think I did since making a double-click on the left side bar with the line numbers did not show the blue icon. Now everything freezes and after a short while I get the error message "oh no" and the code in the js file under Sources is not shown anymore. I have to close the damned browser.

The multiple options on the right side of the tools under Sources do not show any breakpoint, neither active nor unactive. Resources shows the tree with the JS files in my application but I do not see the code when i double-click any file.

Is my breakpoint active ?? How to solve this ??

P.S. - The application freezes and causes a short dump only when I call the developer tools.